# Iterative Tree Plot for the Sum of an Integer's Digits Squared

Tags: graphs-and-networks, number-theory

I am trying to make a graph that depicts integers $< 100$ mapping to the sum of their digits squared. I can do this for one iteration, but I don't know how to do it for more than one, or until the new integer $n$ maps to itself. What I have is:

```
TreePlot[Table[i -> ((Mod[i, 10])^2 + ((i - Mod[i, 10])/10)^2), {i, 99}]]
```

I'm a *Mathematica* beginner so forgive me if this is an obvious or easily answered question.

[image: my attempt]

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the question,but `Graph@Table[DirectedEdge[n, Tr@IntegerDigits@n^2], {n, 100}]`

Comment: Or perhaps `Graph@Table[DirectedEdge[n, Tr[IntegerDigits[n]^2]], {n, 100}]`

Comment: @belisarius Thank you, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had interpreted the question a bit differently. The word "iterative" in the question led me to think that OP might want to see the graphs connecting the [happy numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HappyNumber.html) and [unhappy numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnhappyNumber.html) in *Mathematica*. Here's how to get the two graphs:

```
nums = Table[NestWhileList[Composition[#.# &, IntegerDigits], k,
                           (FreeQ @@ Through[{Most, Last}[{##}]]) &, All],
             {k, 99}];
happy = Select[nums, MemberQ[#, 1] &];
unhappy = Complement[nums, happy];

happyGraph = Graph[Union[Flatten[(DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1]) & /@
                   happy]]]
```

[image: happy number graph]

```
unhappyGraph = Graph[Union[Flatten[(DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1]) & /@
                     unhappy]]]
```

[image: unhappy number graph]

Note the number cycle which the unhappy numbers tend to.

(I had elected to omit the formatting options I used, as they were quite *ad hoc* and annoying to tweak. If anybody can produce better layouts of these graphs, feel free to edit my post!)

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. I was unaware that they had a term for them.

Comment: @J.M. https://ubpdqnmathematica.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/happy-numbers/

Comment: @ubpdqn, very cute! Tho, the graph embedding algorithms leave something to be desired in this case; the overlapping in some places is annoying.

Comment: I'm not sure is you  had _"interpreted the question a bit differently"_. Methinks our results are the same...

Answer (score 3):

Just to ensure this one isn't going to engross the unanswered internal bag. 
As I said in a comment the following might work for two "iterations":

```
base = List /@ Range@100;
base1 = {#, Tr[IntegerDigits[#]^2]} & /@ base[[All, -1]];
base2 = {#, Tr[IntegerDigits[#]^2]} & /@ base1[[All, -1]];
DirectedEdge @@@ Union[base1, base2];
Graph[%, GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the expression for the nth iteration is:

```
f[base_, n_] := Graph[
  DirectedEdge @@@ 
   Union @@ 
    Rest@NestList[{#, Tr[IntegerDigits[#]^2]} & /@ #[[All, -1]] &, 
      base, n], GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"]
```

Invoke as

```
f[List /@ Range@200, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]