# Producing a particular sequence of integers recursively

Tags: integer-sequence, discrete

I am supposed to write a function which computes the next integer in a sequence from the given one.

For example:

```
nextval[57]
```

should give mm

> `74`

I need to make sure this function checks for positive integers, and I need use the Mathematica function `IntegerDigits`, which returns a list of the individual digits of any integer `n`.

For example:

```
IntegerDigits[57]
```

> `{5, 7}`

The overview of this is to basically take any positive integer, say 57, square the individual digits and add them to get a new integer.

```
5^2 + 7^2 = 25 + 47 = 74
```

I know I am supposed to make function using `Module`, but might it also use an `If` statement?

Comment: Total[IntegerDigits[57]^2]

Comment: [A related thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86979).

Answer (score 5):

```
nextVal[x_Integer?Positive] := Total[IntegerDigits[x]^2]
```

The sequence can be readily generated using [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html)

```
seq = NestList[nextVal, 57, 27]

(*  {57, 74, 65, 61, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 
     42, 20, 4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16}  *)
```

The function to generate the sequence is expressible as a [`DifferenceRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot.html)

```
sf = FindSequenceFunction[seq]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
seq == sf /@ Range[Length[seq]]

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

is this what you want?

```
nextval[x_] := Total[IntegerDigits[x]^2];
nextval[57]
```

Also you can make this sequence which starts with 57 (lets take 20 steps)

```
y = 57;
steps = 20;
S = {};
nextval[x_] := Total[IntegerDigits[x]^2];
For[i = 1, i <= steps, i++, t = nextval[y]; y = t; AppendTo[S, y]]
S
```

> {74, 65, 61, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 
>   4, 16, 37}

after some steps you get the repeated sequence 37,58,89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16